# application or session not available to background thread

Tags: spring, wicket, spring-annotations

### Dev environment

java + Wicket + hibernate + spring

### Description

web session is not available inside @Async method when it invoked from ui.

I have a button in a page, when the user clicks the button it invokes "importContactInBackground" method.

### Spring xml configuration

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="commonTaskExecutor"/>
<task:executor id="commonTaskExecutor" pool-size="5-10" queue-capacity="20"/>
```

### @Async method in bean class

```
@Async
public void importContactInBackground(File file)
{
    importService.import(file);
    CustomSession customSession = (CustomSession)Session.get();//throws exception
    LOGGER.info("Contacts are imported by {}", customSession.getUsername());
}
```

### Exception

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: There is no application attached to current thread commonTaskExecutor-2
at org.apache.wicket.Application.get(Application.java:235)
at org.apache.wicket.Session.get(Session.java:175)
```

Comment: sorry it's not much clear, can you provide some more information

Answer (score 0):

I have found something here [working-with-background-jobs](http://wicketinaction.com/2014/07/working-with-background-jobs/) and it works